# Break a link a across multiple lines

Tags: html, css

I have a very long link which I need to display in its entirety, however, the link is overflowing and not wrapping. Any ideas about how I can break the text up?

Comment: could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: There's nothing special about links that prevents them from wrapping.  You must be doing something to make them overflow rather than wrap.  Have you looked at the CSS properties in the inspector?

Comment: @RichieHindle Links are special in the sense that it is all one word and therefore you need to break at the word and not a white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use word-break

```
word-break: break-all
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is this CSS attribute:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

This will allow you to break the word it's self and not just at white space.